# Is openJdk upgrading to 8u292 break my aosp build system?

Tags: java, android, build, tls1.2, ninja

Software environment:

- Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server;
- Android AOSP 8.0;
- OpenJDK 8;

It works very well util yesterday I upgraded my OpenJDK from 8u282 to 8u292. Now the broken building log says:

```
Ensuring Jack server is installed and started
FAILED: setup-jack-server
/bin/bash -c "(prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin install-server prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-launcher.jar prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-server-4.11.ALPHA.jar  2>&1 || (exit 0) ) && (JACK_SERVER_VM_ARGUMENTS=\"-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:+TieredCompilation\" prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin start-server 2>&1 ||
 exit 0 ) && (prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin update server prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-server-4.11.ALPHA.jar 4.11.ALPHA 2>&1 || exit 0 ) && (prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin update jack prebuilts/sdk/tools/jacks/jack-4.32.CANDIDATE.jar 4.32.CANDIDATE || exit 47 )"
Jack server already installed in "~/.jack-server"
Launching Jack server java -XX:MaxJavaStackTraceDepth=-1 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:+TieredCompilation -cp ~/.jack-server/launcher.jar com.android.jack.launcher.ServerLauncher
Jack server failed to (re)start, try 'jack-diagnose' or see Jack server log
SSL error when connecting to the Jack server. Try 'jack-diagnose'
SSL error when connecting to the Jack server. Try 'jack-diagnose'
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
10:11:50 ninja failed with: exit status 1
```

I checked the log in ~/.jack-server/log/xxxx-0-0.log. It has nothing about error.

I use `curl` command to connect to the server, it says:

```
$ curl https://127.0.0.1:8076/jack
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to 127.0.0.1:8076
```

I changed the script in prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin to print the $CURL_CODE, samed as my shell curl command, report error code 35.

This url discussed about samliar problem:
https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1060536-start-0.html

But I am not sure.

Here is the source script link which prompts the above error:
https://android-opengrok.bangnimang.net/android-8.1.0_r81/xref/prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin?r=692a2a62#89

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have same issue and it was fixed by removing "TLSv1, TLSv1.1" in jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms configuration in file /etc/java-8-openjdk/security/java.security.

Comment: Yea ... but I think that's what you want to **avoid** doing, since you are **reducing** security for your Java installation.  (And you will most likely have to repeat this each time you update the installation.)

Answer (score 3):

I think that there is a good chance that it is this:

- https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8202343

Basically, they have turned off (default) support for TLS 1.0 and 1.1, starting in 8u291.  These versions of TLS are old, insecure and deprecated; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

This is mentioned in the 8u291 release notes.

My advice would be to find out why your build system is not using TLS 1.2 or later.  Then upgrade / fix that.

---

You can test if this is the problem by running `curl` with the `--tlsv1.2` option.

Comment: $ curl -vv https://127.0.0.1:8076/jack --tlsv1.2
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8076...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8076 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to 127.0.0.1:8076
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to 127.0.0.1:8076

Comment: $ curl -Version
curl 7.68.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.68.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1f zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.7 libidn2/2.2.0 libpsl/0.21.0 (+libidn2/2.2.0) libssh/0.9.3/openssl/zlib nghttp2/1.40.0 librtmp/2.3
Release-Date: 2020-01-08
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS brotli GSS-API HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB PSL SPNEGO SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets

Comment: Maybe try `--tlsv1.3`?  If that fails, try turning on SSL debugging on the server side to get clues as to why the server is disconnecting during the negotiation.

Answer (score 2):

removing "TLSv1, TLSv1.1" in jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms configuration in file /etc/java-8-openjdk/security/java.security.

It work for me.

Ubuntu update jdk 8u292 background, so it hard related to jdk .

Firsty, Some info link to change Jack port , I had change Jack port but it doesnot work.

Secondly, I have try update ubuntu16.04.2 and ubuntu16.04.7. but error of "SSL error when connecting to the Jack server. Try 'jack-diagnose'" still occurs.

Thanks @Guillaume P  a lot.