# Rebuild android code with error “SSL error when connecting to the Jack server. Try 'jack-diagnose”

Tags: android, curl, openssl, libcurl, android-source

System: ubuntu 18.04
environment：VirtualBox
The first time I compiled the AOSP source code on Ubuntu 18.04, it passed, and the second time I compiled it failed.
Here is an error message.

```
[ 10% 538/4980] Ensuring Jack server is installed and started
FAILED: setup-jack-server 
/bin/bash -c "(prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin install-server prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-launcher.jar prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-server-4.11.ALPHA.jar  2>&1 || (exit 0) ) && (JACK_SERVER_VM_ARGUMENTS=\"-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:+TieredCompilation\" prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin start-server 2>&1 || exit 0 ) && (prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin update server prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-server-4.11.ALPHA.jar 4.11.ALPHA 2>&1 || exit 0 ) && (prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin update jack prebuilts/sdk/tools/jacks/jack-4.32.CANDIDATE.jar 4.32.CANDIDATE || exit 47 )"
Jack server already installed in "/home/user/.jack-server"
Communication error with Jack server (35), try 'jack-diagnose' or see Jack server log
SSL error when connecting to the Jack server. Try 'jack-diagnose'
SSL error when connecting to the Jack server. Try 'jack-diagnose'
[ 10% 541/4980] build out/target/product/rk3399_mid/obj/ETC/precompiled_sepolicy_intermediates/precompiled_sepolicy
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
22:32:18 ninja failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (01:11 (mm:ss)) ####

Build android failed!
```

Generate error reports

> /prebuilts/sdk/tools/report/18577$ unzip jack-report.18557.zip
> Archive:  jack-report.18557.zip
> inflating: report.18557.txt
> inflating: launcher.jar
> inflating: config.properties
> creating: logs/
> inflating: logs/outputs.txt
> inflating: logs/jack-server-0-2.log
> inflating: logs/jack-server-1-0.log
> inflating: logs/jack-server-0-0.log
> extracting: logs/jack-server-0-0.log.lck
> inflating: logs/jack-server-0-1.log
> inflating: server-1.jar
> creating: jack/

report.18557.txt :

```html
 ps -o "pid args" | grep com.android.jack.launcher.ServerLauncher | grep -v grep | awk '{print dump-report}' |  xargs kill -3

$ id -u
1000

$ ps -A -o "uid pid args" | grep com.android.jack.launcher.ServerLauncher | grep -v grep
 1000  6708 java -XX:MaxJavaStackTraceDepth=-1 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:+TieredCompilation -cp /home/zhangying/.jack-server/launcher.jar com.android.jack.launcher.ServerLauncher

$ lsof -i TCP:8376 -l
COMMAND  PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    6708     1000   21u  IPv6  58493      0t0  TCP localhost:8376 (LISTEN)

$ lsof -i TCP:8377 -l
COMMAND  PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    6708     1000   23u  IPv6  58499      0t0  TCP localhost:8377 (LISTEN)

$ cat "$JACK_CLIENT_SETTING"
# Server settings
SERVER_HOST=localhost
SERVER_PORT_SERVICE=8376
SERVER_PORT_ADMIN=8377

# Internal, do not touch
SETTING_VERSION=4

$ cd "$JACK_HOME"; ls -l -R -n .
.:
total 10412
-rw------- 1 1000 1000    2097 May  2 10:04 client.jks
-rw------- 1 1000 1000    2814 May  2 21:48 client.pem
-rw------- 1 1000 1000     356 May  2 10:12 config.properties
drwxr-xr-x 2 1000 1000    4096 May  2 10:04 jack
-rw------- 1 1000 1000 5102506 May  2 10:04 launcher.jar
drwx------ 2 1000 1000    4096 May  2 21:48 logs
-rw------- 1 1000 1000     982 May  2 22:39 report.18557.txt
-rw------- 1 1000 1000 5522186 May  2 10:04 server-1.jar
-rw------- 1 1000 1000    2066 May  2 10:04 server.jks
-rw------- 1 1000 1000    1042 May  2 21:48 server.pem

./jack:
total 0

./logs:
total 32
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000   689 May  2 22:03 jack-server-0-0.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000     0 May  2 10:20 jack-server-0-0.log.lck
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000   585 May  2 10:23 jack-server-0-1.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000   689 May  2 10:19 jack-server-0-2.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000   585 May  2 10:16 jack-server-1-0.log
-rw------- 1 1000 1000 13411 May  2 22:39 outputs.txt

$ curl --version
curl 7.58.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.58.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1 zlib/1.2.11 libidn2/2.0.4 libpsl/0.19.1 (+libidn2/2.0.4) nghttp2/1.30.0 librtmp/2.3
Release-Date: 2018-01-24
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy PSL 

$ JACK_EXTRA_CURL_OPTIONS=-v jack-admin list server
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8377 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /home/zhangying/.jack-server/server.pem
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to localhost:8377 
* Closing connection 0
SSL error when connecting to the Jack server. Try 'jack-diagnose'

$ jack-admin server-stat
Getting statistic from background server
SSL error when connecting to the Jack server. Try 'jack-diagnose'

$ base64 --version
base64 (GNU coreutils) 8.28
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Simon Josefsson.

$ (echo amFjaw==;echo LXNlcnZlcg==) | base64 --decode
```

I get the same error when I switch to Ubuntu 16.04.Below is a list of the installed Curl versions of Ubuntu 18.04.

> 

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

curl/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.13 amd64 [installed]
libcurl3-gnutls/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.13 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libcurl4/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.13 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libcurl4-openssl-dev/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.13 amd64 [installed]

**I have tried many ways, but I can't solve it. Please help me,thanks.**

Comment: my android version is android 8.1

Comment: I have same issue in ubuntu22 and android7

Answer (score 28, accepted):

After the two steps below were applied, the AOSP was successfully built.

1. Remove TLSv1, TLSv1.1 from jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms in /etc/java-8-openjdk/security/java.security file
2. Restart the jack server:
   cd /prebuilts/sdk/tools/
   ./jack-admin kill-server
   ./jack-admin start-server

Comment: Thanks, as a note, no need to start the server after stopping it. It will be started again by ninja

Comment: very useful.  work for me thk you very much

Comment: removing TLSv1, TLSv1.1 from java.security file working for me. Thanks a lot, May i know what is happening here? how removing TLS is fixing this issue ?

Comment: @vijaypanwar TLS versions 1.0 and 1.1 are now deprecated (https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2018/10/browser-vendors-unite-to-end-support-for-20-year-old-tls-1-0/)
So those algorithms are disabled by default in the Java config. I'm guessing that the jack client is using one of those TLS versions to connect to the server because it hasn't been updated yet.

Comment: work in ubuntu22 with android7.It was very easy to modify becasuse there is one line contains TLSv1

Comment: don't forget restart jack-server and the path :prebuilds/sdk/tools where the jack-admin exist

Comment: Keep in mind if you're using something like sdkman or have serval java installations your java home may be in a less intuitive place...

Answer (score 4):

I just found the answer, see the link below
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67330554/is-openjdk-upgrading-to-8u292-break-my-aosp-build-system)

Change the code to this,
from /etc/java-8-openjdk/security/java.security remove TLSv1, TLSv1.1.

> jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, 
> DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, 
> include jdk.disabled.namedCurves

Answer (score 4):

I just want to give all the different ways to solve the problem.
There are few ways to overcome this problem, one may work for someone -

1. Try to simply restart the jack server by below command at your android root folder

   ./prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin kill-server

   ./prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin start-server
2. Try to reduce the number of concurrent services in file $HOME/.jack-server/config.properties
   Code:

   jack.server.max-service=4

Try to make this value 2 or 1.

3. If jack server is not running or it hangs when try to run. Than try removing TLSv1, TLSv1.1 from rom /etc/java-8-openjdk/security/java.security

Solution 3 Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

A way to fix that in your *Dockerfile* :

```
USER root

# Fix jack server SSL issue during build
RUN perl -0777 -i -p -e 's/(jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=.*?), TLSv1, TLSv1\.1/$1/g' \
     /etc/java-8-openjdk/security/java.security
```